# C: comparing two strings from a struct

Tags: c, string, pointers, struct, strcmp

I am almost brand new to C and was wondering how to compare strings from two separate struct member-variables. Maybe providing my code will bring clarity to what I am asking.

I have the following structure:

```
typedef struct mentry {
     char *surname;
     int house_number;
     char *postcode;
     char *full_address;
} MEntry;
```

I want to compare two seperate MEntry variables. I want to check if the surname of both entries is the same. So, I've written the following method:

```
 int me_compare(MEntry *me1, MEntry *me2) 
 {

     int surnameResult;


     char me1Surname = *(me1->surname);
     char me2Surname = *(me2->surname);

     surnameResult = strcmp(me1Surname, me2Surname);
     return surnameResult;
}
```

When I compile my program I get the following messages:

```
 mentry.c:30:6: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  surnameResult = strcmp(me1Surname, me2Surname);
```

Am I wrong in thinking that the line:

```
 char me1Surname = *(me1->surname);
```

sets me1Surname equal to the value of surname and not the address of surname?

I also get another warning saying:

```
"In file included from mentry.c:2:0:
 /usr/include/string.h:140:12:note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument  is of type ‘char’
extern int strcmp (const char *__s1, const char *__s2)"
```

Can someone explain why this warning appears?

Comment: The variables `me1Surname` and `me2Surname` are *single characters*. Call `strcmp` with the actual structure members instead.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Would that involve writing the following line  `surnameResult = strcmp(*(me1->surname), *(me2->surname));`

Comment: Don't use the dereference operator. That's will get you the value where a pointer is pointing. Because the pointers are pointing to a single character, the dereferencing of the pointer will give you a single character. Drop the asterisks in the call to `strcmp`.

Comment: Thank you. That seems to have fixed it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying too hard:

Try the obvious way:

```
int me_compare(const MEntry *me1, const MEntry *me2) 
{
  return strcmp(me1->surname, me2->surname);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I think it works.  I was wondering though, how that line is able to tell if both values are the same?

Comment: @cgy95 that's how [`strcmp`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) works. Which part of the [`strcmp` documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) did you not understand?

Comment: The notes I have have the function definition as the following: `int strcmp(const char s[], const char t[])`. I was wondering why the function can compare two pointer values and not the char values that they point to, in this case.

Comment: 1. `int strcmp(const char s[], const char t[])` is strictly the same as `int strcmp(const char *s, const char *t)`. 2. `strcmp` does not compare pointer values, but it compares the strings _pointed_ by the `s` and `t` parameters.

Comment: Ah, so they are technically different functions that do the same thing then?

Comment: No, there is only _one_ `strcmp` function. This function can be _declared_ as `int strcmp(const char s[], const char t[])` or as `int strcmp(const char *s, const char *t)`. It's two different notations for the same thing.

Comment: Thank you for giving me clarity on that issue.

Answer (score 2):

Compare string without using string library. 
This method compare string if the same it will return the value 0 if both string are equal. Pass in the struct pointer inside the method will do.

```
int compareStr(char *s, char *t)
{

    char t1 = *s;
    char t2 = *t;
    int x;

    while (t1 != '\0' && t2 != '\0') {
        x = (int)(t1 - t2);
        if (x ==0) {
            s++;
            t++;
            t1 = *s;
            t2 = *t;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }


    return x;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this simple example. Just need to make two `MEntry` struct objects to test it, and compare the pointer surnames within the struct, by using their address instead.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char *surname;
    int house_number;
    char *postcode;
    char *full_address;
} MEntry;

int me_compare(MEntry *me1, MEntry *me2);

int
main(void) {
    MEntry me1 = {"McLeod", 27, "3432", "27 Baker Street, London"};
    MEntry me2 = {"Baggins", 19, "3242", "145 Bag End, Shire"};

    if (me_compare(&me1, &me2) == 0) {
        printf("Surnames are identical.\n");
    } else {
        printf("Surnames are different.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

int 
me_compare(MEntry *me1, MEntry *me2) {
    int surnameResult;

    surnameResult = strcmp(me1->surname, me2->surname);

    return surnameResult;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That's awesome. ill allow me test it.

Comment: Data is being parsed from a file to make new MEntry

Comment: Meldrew, Victor
1 Happenstance Place, London
N11 3SR
We take in a full address line and parse it into an MEntry struct. The MEntry's I create are then to put in a dynamic hash table.

Comment: Yeah nice. Well you looked like you found you're answer. Good luck!